# Display wishlist sidebar on all catalog pages

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, layout, catalog, wishlist

I am trying to have the wishlist sidebar on my site display on all catalog pages, as the cart sidebar does. As of now the only way it displays is if you add a product to the wishlist.

Comment: To clarify, you're wanting to show the wishlist even if it is empty?

Comment: @zigojacko yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override the `_toHtml` method in the `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Sidebar` class.  It checks if there are items in the wishlist before calling `parent::_toHtml()`. Remove this conditional and you see the empty wishlist block in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

In PHTML template file, you can add this PHP code to wherever you want

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_wishlist_top'); ?>
```